# Imperatives with "more" and "less"

Tags: grammar

I'm really confused about where to put the words "more" and "less" in an imperative sentence.

For example, in the imperative "Wash your hands **more**", MORE is written after the noun.

However, in "Eat **less** candy" we put LESS before the noun.

As far as I know, MORE and LESS are adverbs in this context, so should we always put them after the verbs?

I also wish to know if both "Do **more** exercise" and "Do exercise **more**" are grammatically correct?

Can you guys show me where to put MORE and LESS in imperatives?

Comment: _Less_ is not an adverb in “eat less candy”. Adverbs do not modify or determine nouns the way _less_ does here – that’s what we have adjectives and determinatives for.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I disagree. What role do you think it plays in just *Eat less!* Why would adding a noun as a third word change the modification of the verb?

Comment: @Jason In “eat less”, _less_ modifies the verb. In “eat food less”, it still modifies the verb. In “eat less food”, you could parse the sentence as having _less_ modify the verb, but that’s a stretch. Compare “eat quickly”, “eat food quickly” and “eat quickly your food” – the latter is unnatural and clumsy, not the natural word order. The same applies to “eat less food” if _less_ is taken as an adverb. Adverbs that modify verbs not usually inserted between the verb and the object in simple sentences like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the examples you give, moving the adverb of "more" or "less" alters what word it is modifying. Compare:

> Eat **less** candy
>
> Eat candy **less**

Either of these are grammatically correct and convey different meanings.

In the first, **less** is more describing *candy*, saying that "you should eat a smaller amount of candy". This can either in general (eg. going from eating 5 candy bars a day to 2 candy bars a week), or in the specific event this statement would be said (eg. a group is sharing a bowl of candy and one person has taken half of the candy bars for themselves).

In the second, **less** feels like it is describing the phrase *eat candy*. It is a shorter way of saying "Eat candy less [often]". It more describes the amount of candy-eating times, as opposed the amount of candy eaten (i.e. going from eating 5 candy bars a day to 6 candy bars once a week). In this sense "eating candy" is being treated as an activity, and one that someone should do less often.

---

When making statements like these, it then becomes important to identify whether the action you want "less" or "more" of is more of a discrete activity or a continuous habit. In the case of "washing hand" compare:

> Wash **more** [of your] hands
>
> Wash your hand **more**

The first sense sounds strange, mostly because you only have as many hands as you have (usu. two). You can't wash more of your hands. This then has a meaning toward " wash further up your arm" or "wash for more time". Note, that if the intended meaning is to do a more thorough job of washing one's hands, then **Wash your hands better** would probably be used.

The second sense makes sense, as **more** is modifying "wash" and treating "wash your hands" as an activity. It is stating that one should wash their hands *more often* than they currently do (eg. twice a day to 5 times a day).

---

For the "do more exercise" (which doen't currently make sense)" here are some options with their nuance in parenthesis.

> 1. Exercise more (exercise[verb] should be done more often or a longer period of time)
> 2. Do more exercises (do more *types of excercises*[noun])
> 3. Do the exercises more (do a specific *set of exercises*[noun] more often)

**This again follows the same pattern (for simple commands) that when a modifier comes between a verb and its object, it modifies just the object (usu. in terms of degree). On the other hand if it comes after the object, typically the verb-object phrase is treated as an activity and the modifier describes *how often*.**

Comment: Nice post, but *less* is not an adverb in *less candy*, it's a determinative.

Comment: Ironically, I disagree with this answer not because I think *less* ***isn't*** an adverb—but because I interpret it as ***being*** an adverb in *both* versions of the sentence. (You imply it's not an adverb when you say it modifies *candy*. But I don't think it does.)

Comment: @JasonBassford What would be a better way of describing the differences, using more grammatically appropriate terms?

Comment: @katatahito Well, it's a matter of interpretation. Depending on how you look at it, *less* may or may not be an adverb. If I forget how we normally speak, I would think that *eat less candy* would sound strange when thinking of *less* as an adverb, because it's not in in a position where you'd expect. However, I think the two seem different because when we hear *eat candy less* we mentally hear *eat candy less* ***often***, even though the word isn't actually there. In short, I *personally* think it's being used adverbially in both cases, because it's modifying *eat* in both cases.

Comment: @JasonBassford So what would do about the fact that “eat less sweets” and “eat fewer sweets” mean **exactly** the same thing and differ only in whether you follow the prescriptive rule that _less_ modifies non-plurals while _fewer_ modifies plurals? _Fewer_ does not function as an adverb at all. In normal English, _less_ does not modify _eat_ in “eat less candy”; it modifies _candy_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't agree that they mean the same thing (neither ***exactly*** nor even necessarily proximately). You can only apply *fewer* to a countable noun. *Less*, however, can apply to a mass noun ***or*** to a verb. (It's impossible to apply *fewer* to a verb, but that's not true of *less*.) And your interpretation is only *your* interpretation; it's not mine.

Comment: @JasonBassford That was precisely my point: in order to tell what _less_ modifies, replace it with something that can either modify only nouns (is only adjectival/determinatival) or only verbs (is only adverbial). The one that sounds grammatical and natural will show what _less_ modifies by extension. “Eat good candy” is natural; “eat well candy” is not => _less_ modifies noun. “Eat candy well” is natural; “eat candy good” is not (unless you use _good_ adverbially, which I’ll prescriptively call non-standard for present purposes) => _less_ modifies verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Now I can't tell if you're agreeing with me or not. ;) To be clear, *my* interpretation is that in both *eat less candy* and *eat candy less*, *less* as an adverb. I'm fine if other people don't agree with me. I acknowledge that this might be subjective. (I know I don't agree that *less* modifies the noun—in either version. Despite possibly not sounding natural in one version, I still follow a single interpretation for both.)